# Understanding "material circumstances" of "personal data" in context

Tags: comprehension

I have read a definition about "personal data" in an ISO/IEC document which states

> Details of the personal or material circumstances of an identified or identifiable natural person.

I don't understand that. Can some one explain that? What does **material circumstances** mean here?

Comment: I would guess it means details of their financial and socio-economic status.

Comment: In legal English, which seems to be the context for the definition, "material" means "of importance", in this case, circumstances (not necessarily financial) which can help define the profile of the individual other than the basic personal details.

Comment: Material here is contrasted to personal. Personal refers to health, marital status; material refers to income and wealth or assets, probably.

Comment: First off, it's not a "sentence".

Comment: @Xanne It’s more an expansion of the category rather than a contrast. The sense of *material* here is more of a contrast with *immaterial* or inconsequential.

Comment: Given that the OP has provided no context, it is impossible to know whether *material* is used here in the sense of having to do with material possessions, or in the sense of being relevant (to something implied by the context). Either way, the use would be well within the standard definitions that can be found in any dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

In a legal sense something is [material](https://thelawdictionary.org/material/) when it's relevant and important. [Circumstances](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/circumstance) are all the facts connected with some matter. Circumstances include even minor details, subordinate and accessory facts.

As used [here](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-data-protection/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/what-is-personal-data/what-is-personal-data/), for example, it essentially means:

> all the facts in any way connected with a person, no matter how minor, so long as the fact is of some importance

This kind of legal definition calls for a fine distinction―perhaps even to the point of splitting hairs―to be made by arbiters of fact on a case by case basis.

Comment: Saying that something is material in this sense requires a context that makes it clear what it is material **to**.